# Coloring all occurrences of some specific characters

Tags: xetex, color

I have been wondering for ages how to do something that is absolutely crucial to the document I am writing. (I usually use XeLaTeX, but I don’t mind changing if required.)

I would like to have a list of characters (presumably Japanese characters, but maybe other ones as well) that would be typeset in a specific way. For instance, put all the ‘u’ and ‘W’ of the document in red.

In my case, the goal is to highlight all the characters (of a text) that are among a set of characters children should learn.

Now, I know I *could* define a macro or a new command for every character and then replace all its occurrences with that macro, but that would be a titanic job because I expect the number of different characters to be around 200.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome! Just have your macro take an argument and then feed the characters to the macro. If they are to be consistently formatted, you want *one* macro which you use to format the 200 characters. You don't need - or want - 200 macros.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is precisely one of the things that XeTeX makes excitingly easy to achieve. See the section *Character classes* in its documentation (`texdoc xetex` in your TeXLive/MikTeX installation or http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf).

Here is an example, but you definitely should check the XeTeX reference for more, especially as you mention Japanese characters, thus you may have to add lines on the model below with "0" replaced by "1", "2", and "3".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\u \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\W \mycharclassRed
% adding the more frequent lowercase w:
\XeTeXcharclass `\w \mycharclassRed


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mycharclassRed   = {\bgroup\color{red}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \mycharclassRed = {\bgroup\color{red}}

\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 0   = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 255 = {\egroup}

\begin{document}

I have been wondering for ages how to do something that is absolutely crucial
to the document I am writing. (I usually use Xe\LaTeX, but I don’t mind
changing if required.)

I would like to have a list of characters (presumably Japanese characters, but
maybe other ones as well) that would be typeset in a specific way. For
instance, put all the `u' and  `W' of the document in red.

In my case, the goal is to highlight all the characters (of a text) that are
among a set of characters children should learn.

Now, I know I could define a macro or a new command for every character and
then replace all its occurrences with that macro, but that would be a titanic
job because I expect the number of different characters to be around 200.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you very much.


\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

> [image]

The lowercase `w` was also added to the  `u` and `W` for highlighting in this example.

Comment: Thank you! You trick allows me not to use LuaLaTeX, which I’m not very keen on

Answer (score 13):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a Lua function, named `color_chars`, that renders in red all instances of characters contained in a pre-defined set of characters. The code uses the function `unicode.utf8.gsub` instead of the more basic `string.gsub`, so that it can handle characters that aren't ASCII-encoded. The code take care *not* to operate on TeX and LaTeX macros.

The LaTeX macros`\ColorMeOn` and `\ColorMeOff`, respectively, enable and disable the operation of `color_chars` on the input stream.

In the following example, all instances of `q` and `Q` are automatically rendered in red if `\ColorMeOn` has been executed.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{luacode,xcolor}
\begin{luacode}
function color_chars ( s )
   s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "(\\?)([%a%@]+)" , function( back, text )
       if back=="" then 
           text = unicode.utf8.gsub (text, "[qQ]", 
               "\\textcolor{red}{%0}" )  
       end
       return back .. text
   end)
   return s
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\ColorMeOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer", color_chars, "ColorMe")}}
\newcommand\ColorMeOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
    "process_input_buffer", "ColorMe")}}

\begin{document}
\ColorMeOn
quick Quiet

\ColorMeOff
quick Quiet
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have error `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex`

Comment: @salimbou - Which TeX distribution and which versions of LuaTeX and of the LaTeX format do you have on your system? (I have `MacTeX2015`, `LuaTeX 0.80`, and `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2` on my system.)

Comment: @salimbou - Do you by any chance execute `\ColorMeOn` *before* `\begin{document}`? That would definitely cause problems...

Comment: This is what shows in log file: `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.12.21)`

Comment: I've just tested, that works _like a charm_  ! Thank you so much!

Comment: @salimbou - Do you get the error message if you run the code exactly the way I've posted it?

Comment: Yes I've copied and pasted your code.

Comment: Message of error indicate that the problem come from  `ltluatex.tex`

Comment: @salimbou - On my system, the log file that's generated from running the code given above shows that exactly 12 external files are accessed during the run; however, *none of them* is named `ltluatex.tex`. Hence, I'm afraid I have no idea what may be happening on your system.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newunicodechar{の}{\textcolor{red}{の}}

\begin{document}

都市というのは、都市としての発展の力学・ダイナミズムがあり、それは行政区分や行政機関とは必ずしも合致しない形で起きるが、東京都を語る上ではそこにある東京という巨大都市のことは無視できないので、ここで（地方自治体としての東京都ではなく）東京都内にある都市や場所としての東京にも一応触れておくと、都市としての東京は、元々は江戸幕府が置かれた江戸であり、徳川家康の都市計画によって築かれ、大いに繁栄した都市である。江戸も幕末の動乱を経る。明治元年の文書から「東京」と表記されるようになった。（江戸時代後期の佐藤信淵の著書『混同秘策』にすでに書かれていた、江戸を「東京」と改称する案を、大久保利通は読んで知っており、明治の新政府発足の折にその案を採用し、提案したことでその名になった。）しかし、日本の行政区画上東京と言う都市は現在は存在しない。

\end{document}
```

Text taken from the page about Tokyo on Japanese Wikipedia. I have no idea of what the text means, nor why the replacement character pops in.

[image]

Comment: @egreg This solution could be used to re-assign a key to a completely different character, and works with LuaLaTeX and friends?

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, but it refuses to redefine a character in the ASCII range (32-127). or problems would arise with control sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Just have your macro take an argument and then feed the characters to the macro. If they are to be consistently formatted, you want *one* macro which you use to format the 200 characters. You don't need - or want - 200 macros.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\learnme[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
ABC\learnme{W}XY\learnme{U}VZ.
\end{document}
```

[image: Red Letter Days?]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I know, but this solution would imply to replace every W by `\learnme{W}`, every U by `\learnme{U}`  and so on.
When you’ve got only U, W and 1 sentence, that’s quite a small problem. But with a set of hundreds and hundreds of characters, constantly changing from text to text, and long texts, that becomes more tricky.