# Errors when trying to color every occurrences of some specific characters (XeLaTeX)

Tags: errors, xetex

I want to color specific character (or word) in my document with red, I know that `XeTeX` can achieve this using `\newXeTeXintercharclass`, `\XeTeXinterchartoks`.

I find this answer [Coloring all occurrences of some specific characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289618/54817) which look like what I need, but errors arise when compiling the code

> ! Too many }'s.  \egroup l.20 I have been wondering for ages how to do something that is absolutely c... You've
>   closed more groups than you opened. Such booboos are generally
>   harmless, so keep going.

**Not working example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\u \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\W \mycharclassRed
% adding the more frequent lowercase w:
\XeTeXcharclass `\w \mycharclassRed


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mycharclassRed   = {\bgroup\color{red}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \mycharclassRed = {\bgroup\color{red}}

\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 0   = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 255 = {\egroup}

\begin{document}

I have been wondering for ages how to do something that is absolutely crucial
to the document I am writing. (I usually use Xe\LaTeX, but I don’t mind
changing if required.)

I would like to have a list of characters (presumably Japanese characters, but
maybe other ones as well) that would be typeset in a specific way. For
instance, put all the `u' and  `W' of the document in red.

In my case, the goal is to highlight all the characters (of a text) that are
among a set of characters children should learn.

Now, I know I could define a macro or a new command for every character and
then replace all its occurrences with that macro, but that would be a titanic
job because I expect the number of different characters to be around 200.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you very much.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The most recent version of XeTeX has raised the number of classes, so 255 should become 4095

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newest versions of xetex has more charclasses. You now need to use 4095 instead of 255 for the boundary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\u \mycharclassRed
\XeTeXcharclass `\W \mycharclassRed
% adding the more frequent lowercase w:
\XeTeXcharclass `\w \mycharclassRed


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mycharclassRed   = {\bgroup\color{red}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mycharclassRed = {\bgroup\color{red}}

\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 0   = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassRed 4095 = {\egroup}

\begin{document}

I have been wondering for ages how to do something that is absolutely crucial
to the document I am writing. (I usually use Xe\LaTeX, but I don’t mind
changing if required.)

I would like to have a list of characters (presumably Japanese characters, but
maybe other ones as well) that would be typeset in a specific way. For
instance, put all the `u' and  `W' of the document in red.

In my case, the goal is to highlight all the characters (of a text) that are
among a set of characters children should learn.

Now, I know I could define a macro or a new command for every character and
then replace all its occurrences with that macro, but that would be a titanic
job because I expect the number of different characters to be around 200.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you very much.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike Ficher, what  characters represented by  `0`  and  `4095`?

Comment: 0 is where everything is by default until you change it. 4095 is the "word boundary".